# Distributing two distinct objects to identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Hiii,
I've been struck with a problem which deals with the distribution of two distinct objects such that p of one type and q of other type into three identical boxes.
As if it were only one object with q copies i'd have used integer partitioning, and if all objects were distinct then could use Stirling Number of second kind.
 But what about this mixed case...?
Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Burnside's lemma I get $\frac16{p+2\choose2}{q+2\choose2}+\frac12\lfloor\frac{p+2}2\rfloor\lfloor\frac{q+2}2\rfloor+\frac13N$, where $N=1$ if $p$ and $q$ are both divisible by $3$, and $N=0$ otherwise.

Comment: tried on one case it's valid for that... Consider number 36 then number of ways to write it as multiple of three factors, (a,b,c).. 36 = 2*2*3*3 it will give answer 8 which is correct

Comment: What is your group action here?

Comment: I wrote program to calculate the answer, tried for 1000 = 2,2,2,5,5,5 , answer is 19...1 1 1000
(1 2 500),
(1 4 250),
(1 5 200)
(1 8 125),
(1 10 100),
(1 20 50),
(1 25 40),
(2 2 250),,
(2 4 125),
(2 5 100),
(2 10 50),
(2 20 25),
(4 5 50),
(4 10 25),
(5 5 40),
(5 8 25),
(5 10 20),
(10 10 10).... matches with your formula...

Comment: @user14111 Is there any more intuitive way to tackle the problem other than this Lemma..

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I am posting an answer using the Polya Enumeration Theorem. As was pointed out, the group acting on the boxes is $S_3$ with cycle index
$$Z(S_3) = \frac{1}{6} a_1^3 + \frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2 + \frac{1}{3} a_3.$$
The pattern repertoire is given by
$$ \frac{1}{1-X}\frac{1}{1-Y}.$$
Substituting into the cycle index it now follows that the desired value is
$$ [X^p Y^q]  \left(
\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{(1-X)^3}\frac{1}{(1-Y)^3} + 
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-X}\frac{1}{1-Y}  \frac{1}{1-X^2}\frac{1}{1-Y^2} +
 \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{1-X^3}\frac{1}{1-Y^3} \right).$$

Now the first term (see the formula at the end) contributes
$$ \frac{1}{6} {p+2 \choose 2} {q+2 \choose 2}.$$
The second term combines the initial segment of the series for $1/(1-X^2)$ of degree at most $p$ with a term from $1/(1-X)$ and the initial segment of the series for $1/(1-Y^2)$ of degree at most $q$ with a term from $1/(1-Y)$ and hence contributes
$$ \frac{1}{2} 
\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} 1 \right)
\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor q/2\rfloor} 1 \right) =
 \frac{1}{2} \lfloor (p+2)/2\rfloor \lfloor (q+2)/2\rfloor$$
and the third term contributes $1/3$ if $p$ and $q$ are both divisible by three because $1/(1-X^3)$ only contains terms of degree divisible by three and $1/(1-Y^3)$  also only contains terms of degree divisible by three.

This confirms the first answer that was posted, namely
$$\frac{1}{6} {p+2 \choose 2} {q+2 \choose 2}
+  \frac{1}{2} \lfloor (p+2)/2\rfloor \lfloor (q+2)/2\rfloor
+ \frac{1}{3} [[p\equiv 0 (3); q\equiv 0 (3)]].$$

Here we have made use several times of the fact that
$$[z^k] \frac{1}{(1-z)^m} = {k+m-1\choose m-1}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but i am not familiar with group theory.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit too slow and the excellent solution using Burnside showed up first. Whether you use Burnside or Polya, I don't think you can avoid cycle indices in this problem.

Comment: At first problem seemed straight forward and thought could be solved using basic approach.